# My JavaScript isn't running inside CodePen and I don't know if it's a bug with my code or not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm practicing some JS in codepen but my code doesn't seem to be working  and I don't know why. I've already tried Googling and searching the question database in stack overflow. Here is all my code I'm using

```js
    var newItemCounter = 1;
    var unList = document.getElementById("list");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var headline = document.getElementById("headline");
    var listItems = document.getElementByID("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
    
    list.addEventListener("click", activateItem);
    
    function activateItem(e) {
      if (e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        headline.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        for (i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
          e.target.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        e.target.classList.add("active");
      }
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", createNewItem);

    function createNewItem() {
      list.innerHTML += "<li>Something new " + newItemCounter + "</li>";
      newItemCounter++
    }
```

```css
    .active{
      background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
    <h1 id="headline">Click a list item to replace this text.</h1>
    <button type="button" id="button">Add new item</button>
    <ul id="list">
      <li>First item</li>
      <li>Second item</li>
      <li>Third item</li>
      <li>Fourth item</li>
      <li>Fifth item</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: where is the codepen?

Comment: Console errors? Did you have a look?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón https://codepen.io/BenSmallwood/pen/jdazqL tell me if this works

Comment: Your codepen works fine tbh, what is not working?

Comment: Your add button does not work because of wrong variable name : list instead of unList for the addEventListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in `var listItems = ...`

```
document.getElementByID("list")
```

to

```
document.getElementById("list")
```

```js
var newItemCounter = 1;
var unList = document.getElementById("list");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var headline = document.getElementById("headline");
var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");

list.addEventListener("click", activateItem);

function activateItem(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    headline.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    for (i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
      e.target.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    e.target.classList.add("active");
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", createNewItem);

function createNewItem() {
  list.innerHTML += "<li>Something new " + newItemCounter + "</li>";
  newItemCounter++
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="headline">Click a list item to replace this text.</h1>
<button type="button" id="button">Add new item</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @BenSmallwood after I fix this bug, your code the button, and item selection by mouse starts to work - run  snippet in my answer

Comment: It is not `list` but `unList` right ? I do not see the list variable ...

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

on line 5 change the getElementByID to getElementById and it will work. 
The "Id" should not be with capital letters

Comment: Check the codepen: https://codepen.io/besartmarku/pen/daJbYd
P.s next time, check console when there are errors as it will show you the error

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.